# Writing to mysql database in Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS

Tags: server, mysql

I am retreiving arp tables from a switch using snmp. I can poll the tables to a text file, but i want to do it to the mysql db. this is the code i am using to poll to text file

```
*/5 * * * *  root /usr/bin/snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -c public(assumed community) -OXsq  (ip adress of switch) .1.3.6.1.2.1.3.1.1.2 > /tmp/S01_ARP.txt
```

How can i modify so that the results are polled to the table arp_tab that i have created in the mysql database
The output come out as

```
atPhysAddress[10][1.172.16.1.5] "80 EE 73 2F 0B 40 "
atPhysAddress[10][1.172.16.1.25] "38 EA A7 6D 2E 8E "
atPhysAddress[10][1.172.16.1.32] "BC 51 FE 50 16 F8 "
atPhysAddress[10][1.172.16.1.200] "00 06 53 FE 39 E0 "
atPhysAddress[10][1.172.16.1.210] "00 18 BA 51 5B 41 "
```

i would want the ip address and the mac address to be mapped into the database

Comment: Well, you can always write some script that calls `snmpbulkwalk` and then parses ans stores the result in MySQL. Also I think Cacti does something similar, so you may check its source code. Can you provide an example of the output you get?

Comment: i will put the output into the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first create mysql database: databasename

create mysql table with 2 text fields for IP and MAC:

```
#!/bin/bash

sed  's/atPhysAddress\[10\]\[//g' arp.txt | sed 's/\]\ \"/\|/g' | sed 's/\ \"/\|/g'> /tmp/arp.new

mysql -uroot -ppassword  databasename <<EOF
load data infile '/tmp/arp.new'
into table tablename
fields terminated by '|'
escaped by '\\\'
lines terminated by '\n';
EOF
```

Comment: I have accepted it as an answer because it has shown me the process to follow, the code doesnt run though and that will be my homework

Answer (score 0):

First, create a database mydatabase, Then, create a table mytable with the fields ip_address, and mac_address. I am assuming you know how to do this. If you don't, specify this.

Try and get your output into a format like the example below :

```
INSERT INTO mytable SET ip_address = '1.172.16.1.5', mac_address = "80 EE 73 2F 0B 40";
```

Then input the SQL commands into the mysql database.

```
mysql mydatabase -u mydatabase_user -p < /tmp/S01_ARP.txt
```

Supply the database password when prompted.